# is it possible to use dojo aspect on a method with no target?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i have a module as follows:

```
define([...], function(...){
  function anothermethod() {...}
  function request() {....}
  request.anothermethod = anothermethod;
  return request;
}
```

Now i want to use dojo aspect before on the `anothermethod` method of the request method (closure). is it possible? If so, what should i put in the target parameter?

```
aspect.before(target, methodName, advisingFunction);
```

And the anothermethod is not called directly. First the request method is called which calls the anothermethod indirectly:

```
require(['dojo/aspect'], function(aspect){
  function anothermethod() {
    console.log('another method');
  }
  function beforeanothermethod() {
    console.log('before another method');
  }
  function request() {
    anothermethod();
  }
  request.anothermethod = anothermethod;
  aspect.before(request, 'anothermethod', beforeanothermethod);
  request();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahwgw5tb/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request` as target.
See:

```js
require(['dojo/aspect'], function(aspect){
  function anothermethod() {
    console.log('another method');
  }
  function beforeanothermethod() {
    console.log('before another method');
  }
  
  function request() {}
  request.anothermethod = anothermethod;
  
  aspect.before(request, 'anothermethod', beforeanothermethod)
  
  request.anothermethod();
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: will this work even if i call the anothermethod inside of request method? 

function request() {
  anothermethod();
}

My case is something similar to this - https://jsfiddle.net/ahwgw5tb/1/

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you already have a target, being `request`:

```
aspect.before(request, 'anothermethod', function() {
  // Do something
});
```

But to answer your original question, no you can't. You always need a target. The target in case of a normal function, would be the local scope where that function lives in, but there's no way to access that.

So, the best solution is to add it to a specific object (`request`) like you did.

Comment: But in my case the anothermethod is not called explicitly. the request method is called first which indirectly calls the another method - https://jsfiddle.net/ahwgw5tb/1/

Comment: Then you just call it with the target, for example `request.anothermethod()` (write that within the `request()` function).