# How to call a regular JavaScript function using dojo aspect

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have mentioned a method inside a JavaScript object in dojo aspect like

```
aspect.before(objectname, "someMethod", function(arg1, arg2) {
        console.warn("aspect.before: ", arg1, arg2);
    });
```

is it possible to call a regular JavaScript function like

```
 function cn(){
      alert("Hello");
    }
```

in dojo aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less a duplicate of : [is it possible to use dojo aspect on a method with no target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281529/is-it-possible-to-use-dojo-aspect-on-a-method-with-no-target)

In your case, you have to use `window` object :

```js
function aMethod() {
  console.log('the method');
}

require(['dojo/aspect'], function(aspect) {



  aspect.before(window, 'aMethod', function() {
    console.log('this runs before');
  });


});

aMethod();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```